# Trying to map entity with type like it has as a member

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am new to nHibernate, here is my code

```
public abstract class DEField : EntityWithSerializableId
{
    public virtual Boolean IsVisibilityDepended { get; set; }
    public virtual DEField VisibilityField { get; set; }
    public virtual String VisibilityExpression { get; set; }  
}
```

I am trying to understand how to map entity that has the same type in its members (`DEField`). This entity could be *nullable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping in this case (property type is same as the Entity) is a simple/standard reference mapping. You can take a look here for more details: [Fluent mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)

References / many-to-one:

```
 ...
 References(x => x.VisibilityField);
```

And that's it. In cases like this, usually Parent Child relation could be indicated. So not only your `DEField` references *itself* as `VisibilityField`, but it also should know (from the point of view of the `VisibilityField`) who is referencing it. The 1) *Parent* reference and 2) *Children* collection:

```
public abstract class DEField : EntityWithSerializableId
{
    public virtual Boolean IsVisibilityDepended { get; set; }
    public virtual String VisibilityExpression { get; set; }  

    public virtual DEField VisibilityField { get; set; } // Parent
    public virtual IList<DEField> ChildFields { get; set; } // Children
}
```

And a bit more complex mapping example then could look like this:

```
 public class DEFieldMap : ClassMap<DEField>
 {
  public DEFieldMap()
  {
     Table("DEFieldTable");
     LazyLoad();
     Id(x => x.Id)
      .Column("Id")
      .Not.Nullable()    
      .GeneratedBy.Identity();
     Map(x => x.IsVisibilityDepended );
     Map(x => x.VisibilityExpression);
     References(x => x.VisibilityField)
      .Class<DEField>()
      .Access.Property()
      .Cascade.None()
      .LazyLoad()
      .Column("ParentId");
     HasMany<DEField>(x => x.ChildFields) // Children     
      .Access.Property()
      .AsBag()
      .Cascade.None()
      .LazyLoad()
      .Inverse()
      .KeyColumn("ParentId");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the <many-to-one> in XML, or it's equivalent in the other mapping systems, just like you would for any other class.